# How to make stealth ssl handshake in Java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, network-programming

I need to make an ssl handshake in a program in order to get some information about the remote server like the public key and cipher suits. I am aware of something called stealth handshake which does not complete the handshake but get the needed information like what I have mentioned. Can any body give explanation on how to do this in Java. I tried to search but not able to find exact concrete method.

Comment: Why? Unless the server demands a client certificate you can complete a normal SSL handshake with it using the builtin SSL classes and then get all the SSL session details.

Answer (score 1):

Stealth? Never heard of this.
You could register a `javax.net.ssl.HandShakeCompletedListener` to your ssl client socket to get the certificate etc. but *after* the handshake has been completed

> javax.net.ssl.HandShakeCompletedListener is an interface implemented
>   by any class which wants to receive notification of the completion of
>   an SSL protocol handshake on a given SSLSocket connection.

And you can also process handshaking data via `SSLEngine`.

Study [JSSE Ref guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLSocket)

Answer (score 1):

Stelath mode not sure about this but I used to do some thing like below to retrieve the certificate chains from the server

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class GetCertificates {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,    KeyManagementException, IOException{
    String host="google.com";
    int port = 443;
    SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    ssl.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new SimpleX509TrustManager()}, null);
    SSLSocketFactory factory = ssl.getSocketFactory();
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host,port);
    SSLSession session = socket.getSession();
    javax.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs = session.getPeerCertificateChain();
    System.out.println(certs[certs.length-1].getSubjectDN());
    // you can display certificates info here and also cipher suites
    session.getCipherSuite();
    session.invalidate();
}
}
class SimpleX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
public void checkClientTrusted(
        X509Certificate[] cert, String a)
        throws CertificateException {
}

public void checkServerTrusted(
        X509Certificate[] cert, String a)
        throws CertificateException {
}

public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return new X509Certificate[0];
}
}
```